# Find position of atom - return nil if not present

Tags: recursion, position, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to find the position of an atom in the list.

Expected results:

`(position-in-list 'a '(a b c d e))` gives 0

`(position-in-list 'b '(a b c d e))` gives 1

`(position-in-list 'Z '(a b c d e))` gives nil.

I have a function that gives the position correctly when the item is in the list:

```
(defun position-in-list (letter list)
  (cond
    ((atom list)            nil)
    ((eq (car list) letter) 0)
    (t                      (+ 1 (position-in-list letter (cdr list))))))
```

The problem is that it doesn't return nil when the item is not present, as if it reaches `(atom list)` nil it will give this error: `*** - 1+: nil is not a number` as when it unstacks, it will try to add the values to `nil`.

Is there a way to adapt this function (keeping the same structure) so that it correctly returns `nil` when the item is not in the list?

Notes:

- I know that there is a `position` function in the library, but I don't want to use it.
- I know my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052756/how-to-find-the-position-of-an-atom-in-list), but the problem I mention above is not addressed.

*** edit ***
Thanks to all of you for your answers. Although I don't have the necessary knowledge to understand all the suggestions you mentioned, it was helpful.

I have found another fix to my problem:

```
(defun position-in-list (letter liste)
   (cond
      ((atom liste) nil)
      ((equal letter (car liste)) 0)
      ((position-in-list letter (cdr liste)) (+ 1 (position-in-list letter (cdr liste)))) ) )
```

Comment: That is both obscure and inefficient. Since you are trying to learn, I would expect you to seek out the ckearest and most efficient. (Which has already been offered by sds,

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to make the recursive function a local function from another function. At the end one would then *return from* the surrounding function - thus you would not need to return the `NIL` result from each recursive call.

**Local recursive function returns from a function**

Local recursive functions can be defined with `LABELS`.

```
(defun position-in-list (letter list)
  (labels ((position-in-list-aux (letter list)
             (cond
              ((atom list)               (return-from position-in-list nil))
              ((eql (first list) letter) 0)
              (t                         (+ 1 (position-in-list-aux
                                               letter (cdr list)))))))
    (position-in-list-aux letter list)))
```

This `RETURN-FROM` is possible because the function to return from is visible from the local function.

**Recursive function returns to another function**

It's also possible to return control to another function using `CATCH` and `THROW`:

```
(defun position-in-list (letter list)
  (catch 'position-in-list-catch-tag 
    (position-in-list-aux letter list)))

(defun position-in-list-aux (letter list)
  (cond
   ((atom list)               (throw 'position-in-list-catch-tag nil))
   ((eql (first list) letter) 0)
   (t                         (+ 1 (position-in-list-aux
                                    letter (cdr list))))))
```

**Test function EQL**

Note also that the default test function by convention is `EQL`, not `EQ`. This allows also numbers and characters to be used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the value returned by the recursive call:

```
(defun position-in-list (letter list)
  (cond
    ((atom list)            nil)
    ((eq (car list) letter) 0)
    (t
     (let ((found (position-in-list letter (cdr list))))
       (and found
            (1+ found))))))
```

Please note that this implementation is not tail-recursive.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's useful to provide a `:test` keyword parameter to pick what equality function we should use, so we do that. It's also handy to give the compiler the ability to tail-call-optimise (note, TCO is not required in Common Lisp, but most compilers will do so with the right optimisation settings, consult your compiler manual), so we use another keyword parameter for that. It also means that whatever we return from the innermost invocation is returned exactly as-is, so it does not matter if we return a number or `nil`.

```
(defun position-in-list (element list &key (test #'eql) (position 0))
   (cond ((null list) nil)
         ((funcall test element (car list)) position)
         (t (position-in-list element 
                              (cdr list) 
                              :test test :position (1+ position)))))
```

Of course, it is probably better to wrap the TCO-friendly recursion in an inner function, so we (as Rainer Joswig correctly points out) don't expose internal implementation details.

```
(defun position-in-list (element list &key (test #'eql)
  (labels ((internal (list position)
              (cond ((null list) nil)
                    ((eql element (car list)) position)
                    (t (internal (cdr list) (1+ position))))))
    (internals list 0)))
```

Comment: you might want to fix errors: :key -> &key , ilst -> list, :postion -> position

Comment: style: it's usually not a good practice to expose internal variables like that - especially if they are otherwise useless or expose internal implementation details. If we provide keyword arguments, the usual expectation is that the caller can do something useful by using it.